# principal_name column not getting updated and application not going to /originalurl

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am currently doing a very basic spring boot application using built in spring boot login form with jdbc.
Also using spring sessions which are using jdbc with the recommended schema.

```
@Autowired 
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, enabled "
            + "from users "
            + "where username = ?").authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority "
            + "from authorities "
            + "where username = ?");      
}
```

Every login attempt there are 2 issues:

1. The column principal_name does not contain data in the spring_session table whenever a row is created because of a login.
2. The application does not redirect to the original url. For example if the application was started at http://localhost:9999/user , it successfully redirects to http://localhost:9999/login displaying the built in login form. It accepts data for the username, password and on clicking submit, am verifying that the call is successful it creates a row in the spring_session table. However it does not automatically go to http://localhost:9999/user but is redirecting to the custom error page.

Comment: Rather than doing it with query have you tried it with userDetailService interface. If you need a demo then I have a demo at git. I can help you with that

Comment: please do share